# Value of char array changes to second iteration value, I want it to be independent

Tags: c

I am under the impression that on each run, in  my Strings array, I am storing at pos a new str since I am declaring it everytime, instead, on the 2nd run if addstr become hello, and on the first run It was hi, the first run hi also becomes hello. I just want a different char array on each run in Strings so later on each position I have a different strings. The requirements is that I can not use malloc, realloc, calloc. I really thought that on the 2nd iteration of the first for loop I am creating on a char str independent of the previous one. Please help me.

```
int pos = 0;
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   if(file [i]=='a')
   {
      char str[5];
      int b=0;
      for(b; b<3; bi++)
      {
         str[b]=file[b];
      }
      Strings[pos]=str;
      pos++;
   }
}
```

Comment: use [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) instead of `Strings[pos]=ptr;`

Comment: @user2065365 The page linked above contains an example that should solve your problem.

Comment: I have the same error, I can not use libc. so I implemented my own strcopy yet same problem it still points to the same one like above.

Comment: update the question with your own version of strcpy then...

Comment: my strcpy simply takes two char arrays, and copies the src to dest, like libc's function. The problem is, the parameters are char[] src, char[] dest

Comment: @hyde please give me a hand here. I don't know how to work with 2d char arrays, please let me know how on each position of the array I can have different value

Comment: @user2065365 Your question does not show what kind of 2D array you have, so kinda hard to help...

Comment: @user2065365 What do you *want*? Everyone here has told you the *problem* and viable solutions. That you're not using libc is a separate issue. That you can handle yourself. You say " I am storing at pos a new str since I am declaring it every time". As written you're saving  a pointer to a **singular** local temp variable, which is undefined behavior once the containing scope of the variable is left (in your case, your for loop).. Get a book on C and learn how variable scope works.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
Strings[pos]=str;
```

It merely sets that array element to the buffer pointed to by 'str'. It does not copy the string. The 'str' buffer never changes, so your entire array ends up pointing to the same buffer.

Rather, at that line you need to copy the string. If you can't use malloc, then your Strings array needs to have buffers at each array element (aka 2 dimensional array). Maybe declare it something like:

```
char Strings[5][5];
```

Then instead of using your strcpy to copy to 'str', copy the string to 'Strings[pos]';

Comment: I can not use malloc, or libc. Please help me.

Comment: Sry, read your post to say you should use malloc. I changed my response to accomodate.

Comment: Could you please give me a quick example.

Comment: PQuinn I don't know what kind of variable to use to store it since I thought on each run I am creating it at a different mem location yet it keeps pointing to the same place. I tried creating a temp variable, to copy it, but the temp variable also on each run points to same location

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fault when I do it that way

Comment: Update your code snippet to show what you are doing. Also, note I changed my declaration for Strings above.

Comment: My String copy simply takes two char arrays, and copies src to dest like the regular strcopy. I just do not know how to point my array to the char variable, since at the end of the day, whatever the temp variable is, is what all the elements in the array are. Using malloc its so much easier, but now I am in pain. Please help me

Comment: For example, if I were to stay Strings[0][0] = temp; and temp was hi, and then Strings[0][1] = temp; and temp was then bye, the [0][0] also becomes bye since they all point to the same variable

Comment: please help me out here bro

Comment: You can't can't use assignment of the string buffers, that's the original problem you started with. You need to use your for loop to copy the individual chars to the buffer 'String[pos]'. Thanks for your up vote.